# Add data from ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online

I want to add data in my map from ArcGIS Online, but ArcGIS does not allow me to complete that operation. I tried on the Add In Manager, by using the option Load All Ads-In without restriction, but it still does not allow me to add data from ArcGIS Online, nor from Add Basemap. I also tried to connect ArcGIS  to a ArcGIS Server, but I can´t find any server address in order to complete that operation. Any suggestions on how I can address this problem, in order to be able to Add Basemaps and Maps from ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Is the map you want to add data to from ArcGIS Online in ArcMap?  If so, what version of ArcMap are you using?

Answer (score 2):

To add maps from ArcGIS online to ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro you need just simple click on Open in ArcGIS desktop button from ArcGIS online map page:

[image]

item.pkinfo file will be downloaded if you prefer to use ArcMap. Open this file in ArcMap. The ArcGIS online map content will be loaded. From ArcMap you can export the data to different formats like ESRI Shape:

[image]

If the map is not public, you will be asked to log in to your ArcGIS online account from ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro.